# Using jquery get command on a XML URL without a file extension?

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps

Im trying to use the live xml data from a program with its own internal webserver (fshost) to place markers on a google map. The dynamic xml is located at It http://109.169.x.x:81/xml which is working and data can be displayed in browser.

I think the problem i am having is that the url has no file extension? I can successfully display markers on a map if i save the webpage first as an xml and point to it, but not directly via its url. I was reading it maybe as the datatype for the xml isnt set correctly? ive tried looking for examples of how to set the correct type, but im having no luck.

Can anyone help please? Many thanks.

```
jQuery.get("http://109.169.x.x:81/xml", {}, function(data) {
  jQuery(data).find("Player").each(function() {
    var marker = jQuery(this);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.find("Latitude").text().replace('N', '+')), parseFloat(marker.find("Longitude").text().replace('W', '-')));
    var marker = new google.maps .Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to force the `dataType` like this:

```
jQuery.get({url: "http://109.169.x.x:81/xml", dataType: "xml", success: function(data)
{
  jQuery(data).find("Player").each(function() {
    var marker = jQuery(this);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.find("Latitude").text().replace('N', '+')), parseFloat(marker.find("Longitude").text().replace('W', '-')));
    var marker = new google.maps .Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
 });
}});
```

Here is the jQuery API reference for `$.get()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

You may also want to use your browser's debugger to examine the response and `data` object. You could use a tool like Fiddler or Chrome to see the XML response itself to make sure everything is as expected, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code, i just get a blank page, even if i use it on the local xml file 'xml.xml' Google chrome/ fiddler gives the url as type text/html

Comment: What happens if you use your browser to manually request the XML URL?

Answer (score 0):

It was the custom webserver causing the issue i think. Moved all files within it and it seems to be working :) ty